# Android - Change Layout with an animation

Tags: android, animation, layout, view, adt

This is my first week of Android development and I am having some troubles so please be patient with me.

This is really simple but all other answers weren't clear or detailed enough for me to apply it.

I am trying to switch from my "activity_main.xml" to a second .xml after a button click. I have already connected the button and put in setContentView(R.layout.view) and it works but I want it to animate. I want the view to come from the right and then the opposite when the user press back. I am doing this in eclipse if that helps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to transition between two activities with a slide animation, yes?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest. I do not know much about activities yet. All I have added is a extra layout .xml file. Do I need to make a new activity or something? (Sorry for the lack of knowledge)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming what you're after is a transition between two activities, here's what you're going to need to do:

1. Create a new Activity class. For this example, lets name it MySecondActivity.
2. In this new Activity class, make sure you're inflating the new layout xml.
3. In the original Activity class, open the new Activity with an Intent, then on the new activity, call the overridePendingTransition with the animation you want:

Code sample:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MySecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

In this example, I'm using Android pre-defined animations. You can create your own too, but I feel this might be enough for your needs.

Hope this helps.